# In Looper, why do they do this to Seth?

Tags: looper

In *Looper*, it is established that permanent physical harm to a young looper will instantaneously affect the old version of the same looper. For example, a looper can send a message to his older self by permanently carving it in his arm.

I assume Abe and his gang know about this. Why is it, then, that in Seth's case:

> when the killers capture young Seth, they torture and mutilate him in order to force old Seth to come to them, then end shooting him up? Wouldn't simply killing young Seth get rid of both Seths? Is the torture simply sadism?

We know the above *will* happen, since something similar happens later in the movie. And if Joe, who is definitely not the sharpest tool in the shed, can figure it out, surely Abe must also know it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Abe says to Joe when he's convincing him to give up young Seth that they won't kill young Seth because it would affect the future too much by not having old Seth around. Since Abe's employers are in the future, I'm guessing they want him to minimize things like that.

Presumably, carving people up is one of the things time travel in Looper allows without too much fuss. Maybe it's self-correcting for minor things like a person not having any arms or legs(!!), or maybe they don't care what young Seth would go on to do as long as old Seth was around when they sent him back in time.

**Edit:** I just checked and their exact words were:

> Joe: You gonna kill him?
>
> Abe: Not if we can help it. It'd be too cataclysmic a change for the future. What we'll do is dangerous in that regards, well not as dangerous as killing him, on top of which a man from the future runs free long enough this time travel shit just fries your brain like an egg. Why the fuck French?

Comment: Oh, I missed the fact Abe's gang didn't kill _young_ Seth! I thought they killed both Seths. Ok, it makes some sense then.

Comment: The answer given is good, but to add (and likely make things more confusing), wouldn't scarring up and removing young Seth's limbs have the potential to greatly affect the future as well? A Seth with arms and legs is likely to lead a different life, and make different choices than a Seth without any limbs.

Comment: @Chad you'd think so, right? But Abe doesn't seem to mind, saying it's dangerous but apparently acceptably so, and neither does the rest of the movie very much. Looper in general had a very lax view of time travel rules in favor of characterization and dialogue. They even lampshade this in the diner scene between old and young Joe, when old Joe screams that if they started talking about it they'd be there all night drawing diagrams and "IT DOESN'T MATTER, IT'S NOT IMPORTANT!". It's more on the Back to the Future end of the time travel movie spectrum rather than the Primer end :)

Comment: @Chad right, I'm not satisfied either.

Comment: @ColonelPanic Wish I could help you, but I can't make up rationalizations that aren't in the movie. They explicitly say "It's dangerous but not as dangerous as killing him". I agree that doesn't make sense, but that's all we know about how time travel works in Looper.

Comment: @jono How there is connection with real-time self and future self if future self comes from different timeline? Timeline A and timeline B cannot be connected while timeline A future and timeline A past can be connected.

Comment: @Boris_yo yeah, that's what you'd expect. But we see in the movie how Future B has their past rewritten in real-time as the Present A changes things, not just limbs and scars but memories as well. I guess that must mean there is no such thing as Future B, he's actually Future A all along?

Comment: @Boris_yo: "Timeline A and timeline B cannot be connected" - you mean if someone tried this with *real-life* time travel, it wouldn't work?